# Is there any way to get the 206px version of a photo via the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get version of a photo that FB uses as the background image for album layouts where one side is always exactly 206px and the other one at least the same, for example [https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p206x206/10401476_409218399235620_1454525834273554679_n.jpg?oh=eda59fce63113796b35c46cc4bec162a&oe=55760EFD&**gda**=1433681435_6b4729404e05493108c271a50c753d7f](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-9/p206x206/10401476_409218399235620_1454525834273554679_n.jpg?oh=eda59fce63113796b35c46cc4bec162a&oe=55760EFD&__gda__=1433681435_6b4729404e05493108c271a50c753d7f) I've scoured both the graph and SO, but am having absolutely no luck here. I'm aware that you can get 3 versions of a photo using type=album/thumbnail/normal ie https://graph.facebook.com/409218399235620/picture?type=album (you'd think this one would work, but they probably never updated it to redirect to the new size?). I've tried all kinds of variants of this knowing that the graph documentation is pretty crap, to no avail.

I've also used the Explorer to for example pull up ?fields=images, but it's never one of the listed images there. I've tried using widths, replacing parts of the URL etc. etc. I am running the checks with a valid access_token.

I've pretty much resigned myself to just resizing myself, but given the time I've spent on this, I thought I'd at least put it out there in case someone else has had the same problem, and come up with a solution.

Comment: This may be a bug with the Facebook API. You could file a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs.

Comment: So many bugs in that api though; you kind of wonder what the point is... But you're right, I probably should. I've gone ahead and just proceeded with downloading and resizing them myself for now. This is probably safer in the long run anyway, but it's annoying to have spent so long on an issue without finding a cause.